# Como desabilitar o botão de voltar em determinadas rotas do React Navigation com React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Olá, estou trabalhando com o `React Navigation` e estou tendo problemas em relação ao botão "voltar" em determinadas telas.

Meu navigator está da seguinte forma:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { FluidNavigator } from 'react-navigation-fluid-transitions'

import SplashScreen from '../../screens/SplashScreen'
import LoginScreen from '../../screens/LoginScreen'
import RegisterCodeScreen from '../../screens/RegisterScreen/RegisterCodeScreen'
import RegisterEmailScreen from '../../screens/RegisterScreen/RegisterEmailScreen'
import RegisterInfoScreen from '../../screens/RegisterScreen/RegisterInfoScreen'
import LanScreen from '../../screens/LanScreen'

export default Navigator = FluidNavigator({
  SplashScreen: { screen: SplashScreen },
  LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen, },
  RegisterEmailScreen: { screen: RegisterEmailScreen },
  RegisterCodeScreen: { screen: RegisterCodeScreen },
  RegisterInfoScreen: { screen: RegisterInfoScreen },
  LanScreen: { screen: LanScreen }
});
```

Preciso que seja bloqueado o "volta" somente nas telas de `LoginScreen` e `LanScreen` e para isso (no momento) estou utilizando o recurso abaixo:

```
export defaut class LoginScreen extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => true);
  }

  // ....

}
```

O problema é que usar o BackHandler faz com que desabilite em todas as rotas e não quero isso... Como resolver?